# Sending Python functions to be executed on a cluster

Tags: python, networking, cluster-analysis

I want to build a 4-5 Raspberry Pi Cluster for a school project and I want to write a library for Python similar to Thread, but instead of running the given function on the same machine in a Thread, I will run it on another Raspberry Pi and then get the response back to the sender.

Should I use sockets and a server-client model for the data transmission via LAN and `exec()` to execute the function on the slave, then send the result back as a message to the initiator?

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) and [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), both take care of spawning processes over a network/cluster and handle the communication between them.

Comment: Regarding Pyro, it won't automatically spawn *processes* for you - you'll have to start a server process on every node yourself. Once running it can however use a thread pool to deal with multiple connections concurrently.  Also the docs are now hosted on RTD http://pyro4.readthedocs.io